# i want to compare two text files in vb.net to check if there are values that are not in list one

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

    Const TEST1 = "\\folder\compare\list1.txt"
    Const TEST2 = "\\folder\compare\list2.txt"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click
    'Declare two dictionaries. The key for each will be the text from the input line up to,
    'but not including the first ",". The valus for each will be the entire input line.

    Dim file1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim file2 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST1)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",") 
        file1.Add(part(0), line)

    Next

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST2)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",")
        file2.Add(part(0), line)
    Next

    AddText("The following lines from " & TEST2 & " are also in " & TEST1)

    For Each key As String In file2.Keys
        If file1.ContainsKey(key) Then
            AddText(file2(key))
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub AddText(ByVal text As String)
     txtResults.Text &= text & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

list 1)12345
list 2)1234
result: 5 is not in list 1

i want to compare two text files in vb.net to check if there are values that are not in list one
The problem im facing is that the lists compare all values that match but i also want a list of values that dont match. I want to show the values in list 1 that are not in list 2.

Comment: Just to understand, you want 2 new lists - The first one being all the keys from `file2` that are not in `file1` and the second being all the ones that match??... And then what do you want to do with the matches / non-matches?? .... Please just clarify exactly what it is you want...

Comment: Please specify sample input and expected output of the program for that input. Also take note of the current output (this way it's easier to understand what you want).

Comment: I want to show the values in list 1 that are not in list 2. see sample list

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, put in an `else` and put the value in another list:

```
For Each key As String In file2.Keys
    If file1.ContainsKey(key) Then
        AddText(file2(key))
    Else
        ...Add to anther list or string here
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
Dim keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2 = file1.Keys.Except(file2.Keys).ToList
```

Assumed list1 `is-superset-of` list2. Otherwise just swap them.

### EDIT

to print it,

```
Dim values = From key In keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2  Select file1(key)
Dim str = String.Join(vbCrLf, values)
AddText(str)
```

Comment: How do you display the result i was using a multiline textbox. AddText(keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2) but i get an Error 1 Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: ok the plot thickens, that works great but ive changed my list to be more complex, list1) {text text text text 1 text text text text 2 text text 3} List2){12} Result){3} error = An item with the same key has already been added